# Move text position inside a nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let longTitleLabel = UILabel()
        longTitleLabel.text = "Profile"
        //longTitleLabel.font = ................
       longTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 31)

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let height: CGFloat = 25
        let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
    }
```

I have this nav bar in my view controller and the text profile on it. Can I change the position in which it is located. For example constraint it to the left and top so it moves it down more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving frame to navigationBar give frame to your label and add it in NavBar like

```
      let longTitleLabel = UILabel()
      longTitleLabel.text = "Profile my boy hello jee wao"
      longTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
      longTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .red
      longTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
         navigationBar.addSubview(longTitleLabel)

         longTitleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
         longTitleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
         longTitleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
         longTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: navigationBar.bounds.maxY).isActive = true
      }
```

Hopefully resolve your issue

[image]

Comment: i want to move the text. like how can i set constraints for the text "profile" iniside the nav

Comment: thats how you can add costraints on that label

Comment: how can i constraint like 20pnts from the left and 20pnts from top