# Cannot set custom large title in NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, swift5

It seems I can only change the large title when using no font. I can’t change the title property when using a custom font.

```
  navigationItem.title = “title”
```

How can I change the large title when using custom font instead of system font?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644055/1780632 
please check my answer ... hopefully it will help

Comment: I don’t want to add a label inside my NavigationBar tho

Comment: `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` 
does this make any sense then ?

Comment: As already stated, I can set a large title, but I can’t change it using a custom font. PrefersLargeTitles is already true of course.

Comment: What actually you want to do ? Are you asking about separate title for large Title and normal title ?

Comment: You just have to set the title for navigationItem.title = "Your Title" and set the navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes and navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes. iOS will automatically change the title sizes and apply the respective attributes.

Answer (score -1):

In the viewDidLoad of your controller just put this code with your specific values of font and color. It will show normal and large title with respective title attributes.

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
navigationItem.title = "Your Title"

navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: Font.medium(15),
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.black
]

navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: Font.medium(25),
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.black
]
```